# The group of invertible matrices with entries in Z

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G=GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$, the group of invertible matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then show that

$G=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z}) : det(A)=1 \,\,\,or -1\}$

Can you help me please?

Comment: Hints: (1) $\det : M_n(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplicative and (2) the adjugate of a matrix with integer entries also has integer entries and the inverse of a matrix is the adjugate scaled by the reciprocal of the determinant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The determinant of a product is the product of the determinants. And the determinant of an identity matrix is $1$.

For the other direction, one way is to use the formula for the inverse in terms of determinants.

Comment: Adding to your hint: Product of two integers is 1, then they are both +1 or both -1.